# Windows Phone Tapping an alarm or Reminder launched Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Scheduled Notifications allow apps to register recurring and one-time alarms and reminders that pop up in the foreground on a predefined schedule. The user experience is similar to the reminders implemented by the built-in calendar app. A user tapping an alarm or reminder launches your app.

how to do that in windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When A user taps on the reminder it navigates on a specified page. That is default operation of reminder.
You just have to specify a navigation uri in a reminder object before adding it.
Here is an example

```
                Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/ShowDetails.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
                reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
                reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
                reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
                reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
                reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
                reminder.NavigationUri = navigationUri;

              //   Register the reminder with the system.
                ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

One more thing this can be done only with reminders not alarms.

Comment: Is that possible user tap on alarm and reminder lunches my application.The alarm & reminder invoke at same time.